# Latex to html conversion

Tags: html, latex, converters, forum

I am building a website with an implemented forum using Xobor. I want to make a button in the toolbar of the Textwindow that can convert Latex to html. Something like [Latex] \sqrt{a^2+b^2} [/Latex] would be great. Alternativly it can also be a button that creates a popup window, where Latex code can be written. Something like this:
[image: Here you can click on the Button fx and a new window pops up, where you can enter latex code, which is then converted]
Here you can click on the Button fx and a new window pops up, where you can enter latex code, which is then converted

I already found converters like Mathjax and Katex but I don't think, that they do what I need, because these tools seem to work only for the website text itself, but not for the forum posts.
I honestly don't know much about html, so maybe I am mistaken (I have a friend that will help me implement these things as soon as I find a tool that is fit to do what we need).

I can create the button itself like this (picture below), but obviously it doesn't convert anything yet.
[image]

So basically what I am looking for, are some lines of Code that I can put in that textbox shown in the picture above, which create a button in the toolbox, to be able to write formulas and other latex math stuff in my forum.

I really hope that this makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After installing katex in my Angular project (npm install ng-katex --save
) I use it like:

Typescript:

```
var equaciones = [' H = \\sum_{i=1}^{m} p_{i} log_{2} (p_{i})']
```

Html:

```
<ng-katex [equation]="equaciones[0]"></ng-katex>
```

Result:

[image]

You can see an example of the result here: [web_example](https://1938.com.es/app-busqueda-documento-web)